# How to have a drop down <select> field in a rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu, input, selectlist

I am creating a scaffold -

```
rails g scaffold Contact email:string email_provider:string
```

but I want the email provider to be a drop down (with gmail/yahoo/msn as options) and not a text field. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can take a look at [the Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) . Anyways , in your form :

```
  <%= f.collection_select :provider_id, Provider.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>
```

As you can guess , you should predefine email-providers in another model -`Provider` , to have where to select them from .

Comment: so the model will be contact.rb, but where should I put that drop down logic ? sorry for naive question, I am new to RoR development

Comment: Your question is OK . If you take a look at the structure of your `app/views/contacts` , you'll find a file `_form.html.erb` . You can try to place it there . This "partial view" is in charge of both creating and updating actions of the scaffold you've generated.

Comment: recommend moving the order(:name) to a scope (which is a method) in the model.  It's not a big deal here but over time you will find that having, what is essentially business logic like this (ordering) on a view template becomes a mess.  Move it to the controller, or ideally the model and make a scope available there that you can use.  One example - if you end up with three screens or templates that use the dropdown, having the order in the views means 3 X duplication.  Having it in the model means it is defined in one place and that's the only place to change it which is good.

Answer (score 63):

Or for custom options

```
<%= f.select :desired_attribute, ['option1', 'option2']%>
```

Comment: <%= f.select :desired_attribute, options_for_select([['opt1'], ['opt2']]) This works for me

Answer (score 17):

You create the collection in the `Contact` controller -

```
app/controllers/contacts_controller.erb
```

Adding

```
@providers = Provider.all.by_name
```

to the new, create and edit methods, using a scope for the `by_name` in the `Provider` model - `app/models/provider.rb` - for the ordering by name

```
scope by_name  order(:name)
```

Then in the view - `app/views/contacts/_form.html.erb` - you use

```
<%= f.collection_select :provider_id, @providers, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```

For rails forms, I also strongly recommend you look at a form builder like simple_form - https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form - which will do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I edited the question and have put another code which worked for me, so just wondering what is the difference in using Select and collection_select as mentioned in below answers ?

Answer (score 11):

This is a long way round, but if you have not yet implemented then you can originally create your models this way. The method below describes altering an existing database.

1) Create a new model for the email providers:
`$ rails g model provider name`

2) This will create your model with a name string and timestamps. It also creates the migration which we need to add to the schema with:
`$ rake db:migrate`

3) Add a migration to add the providers ID into the Contact:
`$ rails g migration AddProviderRefToContacts provider:references`

4) Go over the migration file to check it look OK, and migrate that too:
`$ rake db:migrate`

5) Okay, now we have a provider_id, we no longer need the original email_provider string:
`$ rails g migration RemoveEmailProviderFromContacts`

6) Inside the migration file, add the change which will look something like:

```
class RemoveEmailProviderFromContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :contacts, :email_provider
  end
end
```

7) Once that is done, migrate the change:
`$ rake db:migrate`

8) Let's take this moment to update our models:
Contact: `belongs_to :provider`
Provider: `has_many :contacts`

9) Then, we set up the drop down logic in the _form.html.erb partial in the views:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :provider %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :provider_id, Provider.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
```

10) Finally, we need to add the provders themselves. One way top do that would be to use the seed file:

```
Provider.destroy_all

gmail = Provider.create!(name: "gmail")
yahoo = Provider.create!(name: "yahoo")
msn = Provider.create!(name: "msn")
```

`$ rake db:seed`

Answer (score 7):

`<%= f.select :email_provider, ["gmail","yahoo","msn"]%>`

Answer (score 7):

Rails drop down using has_many association for article and category:

```
has_many :articles

belongs_to :category

<%= form.select :category_id,Category.all.pluck(:name,:id),{prompt:'select'},{class: "form-control"}%>
```

Answer (score 6):

Please have a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001593)

*Either you can use rails tag Or use plain HTML tags*

**Rails tag**

```
<%= select("Contact", "email_provider", Contact::PROVIDERS, {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

***above line of code would become HTML code(HTML Tag), find it below ***

**HTML tag**

```
<select name="Contact[email_provider]">
  <option></option>
  <option>yahoo</option>
  <option>gmail</option>
  <option>msn</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, I am still confused, I understand the <select> code will go in _form.html.erb but where will that select("Contact",) code go ?

Answer (score 4):

In your model,

```
class Contact
  self.email_providers = %w[Gmail Yahoo MSN]
  validates :email_provider, :inclusion => email_providers
end
```

In your form,

```
<%= f.select :email_provider, 
    options_for_select(Contact.email_providers, @contact.email_provider) %>
```

the second arg of the options_for_select will have any current email_provider selected.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to display one thing (human readable) but store another (an integer id).

#### Small example

Here's a small example that helped:

```
<%= form.select(:attribute_name, {cat: 5, dog: 3} )%>
```

The `{cat: 5, dog: 3}` will display "cat" and "dog", but save 5 and 3.

---

#### Real world example

Here's the actual use case. It displays the names of sellers (that humans can read), but saves the sellers' id (an integer):

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :seller_id %>
  <%= form.select :seller_id, seller_names_and_ids(), {include_blank: true}, {required: true, class: "form-control"} %>
</div>
```

And the helper is defined as:

```rb
def seller_names_and_ids
  # We want this to produce a hash of keys (the thing to display) and values (the thing to save, 
  # in thise case the seller_id integer)
  sellers = Seller.all
  h = {}
  sellers.each do |seller|
    thing_to_display = seller.name + " (" + seller.id.to_s + ")"
    thing_to_save_in_db = seller.id
    h.store(thing_to_display, thing_to_save_in_db) 
  end
  h
end
```