# How to do a simple dropdown list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I'm looking to rewrite our company website into ROR. We have the typical row of drop down
menu items (e.g. "Products & Services", "About Us", "Contact", etc).

Does Rails provide a shortcut for building these menus?

Thanks,

P

Answer (score 0):

Not in Rails per se. Read up on [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/); it provides a backbone structure for all that sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select :page, options_for_select(%w[Services About\ Us Contact]) %>
```

(where page is the field name), should work, please check [How to have a drop down <select> field in a rails form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14113057/692622) too for better clarification and examples