# Simple form: grouped nested inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

in my app I have nesting resources for simple form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @member, url: "/assessments/update_invite/#{@token}", method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :assessment_procedure_results do |g| %>
    <%= g.object.skill.skill_group.name %>
    <%= g.input :self_estimation %>
    <%= g.input :skill_id, as: :hidden %>
    <%= g.input :assessment_procedure_member_id, as: :hidden %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit%>
<% end %>
```

with that code I have:

```
**Skill group 1**
Programming <input here>

**Skill group 1**
Testing <input here>

**Skill group 1**
Designing <input here>
```

How can I group fields by `SkillGroup` like:

```
**Skill group 1**
Programming <input here>
Testing <input here>
Designing <input here>
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying for dropdown menu ?

Comment: You must have missed to checkout this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/14113150/2545197

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have a drop down <select> field in a rails form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113057/how-to-have-a-drop-down-select-field-in-a-rails-form)