# Rails Form dropdown select, save to table and display in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu, collection-select

I created a user and program table, and a joined table. Each user has_and_belongs_to_many :programs and each program has_and_belongs_to_many :user.

Using dropdown select, I wanted to select a program and save it to the user. But after I save, the display always shows the text "Program" instead of the actual program name that was selected from the dropdown.

Dropdown select form:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:program_ids, Program.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Choose a Program" ) %>
```

Display programs that the user belongs to:

```
<% @user.programs.each do |program| %>
  <%= program.name %> 
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure if I am saving the program to user correctly or if I am displaying the variable wrong. I followed the idea from [how to have a dropdown select field in a rails form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113057/how-to-have-a-drop-down-select-field-in-a-rails-form).

Any suggestion will help, Thanks!

Comment: can u try this one: `<%= f.select :program_id, Program.all.map {|c| [c.name, c.id] }, {prompt:"Choose a Program"} %>`

Comment: @7urkm3n I tried the code you posted and I get the same result. It just lists as "Program" instead of the actual program name such as "Math".

Comment: how exactly do u want to save `ids`, many or just one id of program ? cuz yr db relationship many to many. and if im not wrong it requires to save it array, not a just integer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to my problem. The dropdown select form and view code stayed the same. It now displays the program associated with the user instead of showing the text "Program".

Added `serialize` to program.rb:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  serialize :program
end
```