# How set "selected" in option ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### in _form.html.erb file I wrote:

```
 <%= f.number_field :tov_id %>
```

and that code produce this html :

```
<input type="number" value="3" name="price[tov_id]" id="price_tov_id" />
```

this code:

```
 <%= select_tag(:tov_id, options_for_select(@tovs,2), :prompt => "select tov" )  %>
```

make this html

```
    <select name="tov_id" id="tov_id">
<option value="">select tov</option>
<option value="1">brake pad</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2" >nut</option>
    <option value="3">bolt</option></select>
```

as we can see : the second parameter to option_to_select respond to selected option 
But when I wrote this:

```
<%= select_tag(:tov_id, options_for_select(@tovs , :tov_id  ), :prompt => "Select tov" )  %>
```

no any selected appear :(

```
    <select name="tov_id" id="tov_id"><option value="">Select tov</option><option value="1">brake pad</option>
<option value="2">nut</option>
<option value="3">bolt</option></select>
```

How can I get the value from :tov_id and put it to options_for_select ?

Comment: I shuld use @price.tov_id instead :tov_id !!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a drop down <select> field in a rails form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113057/how-to-have-a-drop-down-select-field-in-a-rails-form)