# Rails - Updating a value through rails seed for a given user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Apologies for the question, I'm still learning rails. Trying to update a specific user's home cities through a drop down. I followed all the steps as outlined in this question [How to have a drop down <select> field in a rails form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113057/how-to-have-a-drop-down-select-field-in-a-rails-form) and I'm not getting any errors. However, when I go to my rails console and do User.first - the homecities_id is still set as nil. Thank you guys so much for your help.

**edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :homecity %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :homecities_id, Homecity.all, :id, :Hometown %>
</div>
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
  :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

  cattr_accessor :current_user

  belongs_to :homecity, optional: true
end
```

**Homecity.rb**

```
class Homecity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

**Application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :name, :avatar, :homecities])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username,:name, :avatar, :homecities])
  end
end
```

**Migrations**

```
class CreateHomecities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :homecities do |t|
      t.string :Hometown
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddHomecitiesRefToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :homecities, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

**seed.rb**

```
Homecity.destroy_all
bigapple = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"New York City")
techhub = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"San Francisco")
longhorns = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"Austin")
angels = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"Los Angeles")
windycity = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"Chicago")
hcards = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"Washington DC")
amazon = Homecity.create!(Hometown:"Seattle")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a `belongs_to` it's only one `homecity` and it's actually the homecity_id you're trying to pass to devise.

So instead of...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :name, :avatar, :homecities])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username,:name, :avatar, :homecities])
  end
end
```

You should do...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :name, :avatar, :homecity_id])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username,:name, :avatar, :homecity_id])
  end
end
```

And you'll need to modify your edit view to the singular...

```
<%= f.collection_select :homecity_id, Homecity.all, :id, :Hometown %>
```

Finally, do `rake db:rollback` and change `homecities` to `homecity` in your migration and then do `rake db:migrate` again.

Comment: Steve thank you so much for that. Your explanation was super helpful in allowing me to understand better :) Have a great week champ!

Answer (score 2):

`add_reference :users, :homecity, foreign_key: true`

In the migration, only the first argument should be plural. Take a look [here.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

That is why you have `homecitied_id` instead of `homecity_id` in your database, which is not correct.

Also in the view you need to change to `homecity_id`.

```
<%= f.collection_select :homecity_id, Homecity.all, :id, :Hometown %>
```

Comment: Thanks a billion mate for your help!