# How to get some fixed static values in rails form tag drop down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a filter. I have a model with column `status` and I have defined enum status for that column inorder to make it readable. And these statuses are fixed.

**model**

```
class Production < ApplicationRecord    
  enum status:{
    Preproduction:1,
    Postproduction: 2,
    Completed:3
  } 
end
```

And I am trying to filter the table based on the status given by the user. 
The result is filtered only if the user enter the complete name of status like `preproduction`. The controller is as follows:

**controller**

```
    def index
        if params[:filter]
          @productions = Production.where('productions.status like ?', "%#{Production.statuses[params[:filter].capitalize]}%")
        else
          @productions = Production.all
        end    
   end
```

As you can see I am using params to query.

My current form tag looks like this

**index**

```
<%= form_tag productions_path, :method => 'get', :id=> "contacts_search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :filter, params[:filter] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Filter", :name => nil %>
  </p>
  <div id="cresults_div"><%= render 'cresults'%> </div>
<% end %>
```

I have some fixed statuses as follows:

```
Production.statuses => {"Preproduction"=>1, "Postproduction"=>2, "Completed"=>3}
```

Since I am querying the controller with the help of params I cant directly use `f.select` like suggested in some answers. How can I get these keywords `Preproduction` `Postproduction` `Completed` in ad drop down of this text field ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have a drop down <select> field in a rails form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113057/how-to-have-a-drop-down-select-field-in-a-rails-form)

Comment: since you are using `form_tag` so its not possible to use `f.select` instead of that you can use `select_tag` helper.

Comment: @Gabbar i want to retain `filter` attribute and  `params[filter]`. So I tried this `<%= select_tag "filter", options_from_collection_for_select(Production.statuses) :filter, params[:filter] %>` . I am having difficult time getting it right.

Comment: lets try the given solution below, hopefully it can help you. let me know for further guidance.

Comment: Yeah got it. I added what you answered in select tag and I had to make some changes in the controller. Looks like you edited the answer. That's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= select_tag :'filter', options_for_select(Production.statuses, params[:filter]), include_blank: '--Select One Option--' %>
```

in controller: -

```
def index
  if params[:filter]
    @productions = Production.where(status: params[:filter])
  else
    @productions = Production.all
  end    
end
```